# Auth0 - why insufficient scope and what to do with it?

Tags: python, oauth, auth0

I am trying to authnticate with Auth0 and get user data.

```
import json
import requests

payload = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'username': '********',
    'password': '********',
    'client_id': '********',
    'connection': 'Username-Password-Authentication',
    'scope': 'openid'
    # 'scope': 'openid, read:clients, read:client_keys'
    # 'scope': 'read:clients'
}
base = 'https://********.auth0.com'

url = base + '/oauth/ro'
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
response = json.loads(response.content)

headers = {"Authorization": "bearer " + response["id_token"]}
response = requests.get(base + '/api/v2/clients/joebloggs', headers=headers).json()

print response
```

What I keep getting is

```
{u'errorCode': u'insufficient_scope', u'message': u'Insufficient scope, expected any of: read:clients,read:client_keys', u'error': u'Forbidden', u'statusCode': 403}
```

What exactly is wrong and what to do about it?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use an `id_token` for the Auth0 API. You need a specific token for the API (v2) (and in your case you need a `read:client` scope). See here: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2

Comment: Hi Eugenio Pace, what do you mean by 'need a read:client scope'? How do I change scope, scope of what? Can you please provide more details?

Comment: It means that to call the API you need to obtain an _access_token_ that has a `read:client` scope :-). In other words, your request for the token needs to include the `read:client` scope, and if authorized, you will be able to call the API. The `id_token` wouls not have that entitlement.